Counting amount of UV vertices in active UV set by Python script
I trying to get behavior like Maya UVs count display.
But Blender loops make it quite tricky for me. And I am just 3d artist myself so it`s a big deal for me.
Earlier mighty Jaroslav Jerryno Novotny gave an answer to similar question. He suggest script like that:
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object

# Store all UV vertex locations
uv_coords = []
for loop in obj.data.loops:
    uv_loc = obj.data.uv_layers.active.data[loop.index].uv
    uv_coords.append(tuple(map(lambda x: round(x,3), uv_loc[:])))

# Keep only the unique ones and count them
print("object {0} has {1} UV vertices".format(obj.name, len(set(uv_coords))))

Another version on that solution can be simplified:
UVVerts = set()
for uv in bpy.context.active_object.data.uv_layers.active.data: UVVerts.add(uv.uv[:])

But unfortunately both of solutions have critical problem - they relies on UV vert coords and stored them just once. It works just fine for simple situation but did not work in case of overlapping UVs.
Maybe someone here have an idea how to bypass such trouble?
UPD: Additional screenshot added for clearence purpose.


Sorry - could you define the original problem a bit more? What is it exactly that you want to get here? How is the solution not working? Could you just explain in more detail so it's a bit easier to understand the problem?

Some context might be helpful as well - why do you need to count them in the first place? Because if it's about recourses, it seems values are stored for each face corner anyway (that's for cube with 14 UV verts returned with the script)

OK, sorry - I think I get it. So you want UV count if some UVs are for different vertices but are at the same locations as UVs for different vertices. That should be possible to do modifying the original script with some additional logic.

I need UVs count because as an 3D artist i get model vertices budget in their appearance inside Unreal Engine. And engine numbers is quit near UVs count.

Easy dirty way would probably be to have seams marked according to the UV map and count vertices counting the seams twice... But that's not elegant at all. Unfortunately, the API is not very helpful when working with UVs. Pretty sure it's possible, but it's just a bit complex... at least for me. Will try to figure it out, but hopefully someone smarter may help sooner than I manage to work it out if at all.

Wouldn't using a list instead of a set give the same output as Maya ?

No, because of loops concept inside Blender. So if we list all UVs we will get count as much as where connected edges to each UVs (about 24 for a default cube).
And vise versa, if we will count all loops with unique vertex IDs we will miss shared perimeter vertices between UV islands.
I m not sure are youtube links allowed here, but video called "Blender Python: The most confusing part of BMesh" by CG Python channel explained those concepts quite well.

@Gorgious, yeah apparently Blender stores any UV map as values for all existing face corners, so this functionality does not make sense in Blender, but as I understand it would be a useful preview how data would be stored in some game engines.

Here is quite dumb variant but it gave me probably correct count.
Maybe it will be more effective with defined struct for store vectror3 and vector2, not sure.
Anyway, script just enum through mesh loops, created string whom looks like vertex coords + uv coords ((-100.0, -100.0, 100.0)(0.875, 0.75) as example) and added those strings to set:
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object
coll = set()
for index, loop in enumerate(obj.data.loops):
    uvCoords = obj.data.uv_layers.active.data[index].uv[:]
    vertexCoord = obj.data.vertices[loop.vertex_index].co[:]
    dataStr = str(vertexCoord) + str(uvCoords)
    coll.add(dataStr)
print(len(coll))



I think that's a very nice solution. Chances of the verts with overlapping UVs overlapping in 3d is really practically 0 on any models that make sense. Did you remove rounding? Doesn't that cause binary inaccuracy problems? Well, it probably works as accurately as the second version in the question anyway...

I m not think so because actually it s the same data again and again. Like:
`(30.87652587890625, -110.08845520019531, 134.957763671875)(0.625, 0.75)
(30.87652587890625, -110.08845520019531, -65.04224395751953)(0.375, 0.75)
(30.87652587890625, -110.08845520019531, -65.04224395751953)(0.375, 0.75)
(30.87652587890625, -110.08845520019531, 134.957763671875)(0.625, 0.75)
(-169.12347412109375, -110.08845520019531, 134.957763671875)(0.625, 1.0)
(-169.12347412109375, -110.08845520019531, -65.04224395751953)(0.375, 1.0)`

And all comparison is character based, not digital values comparison.

I would probably round the UV coordinates just in case. Vertices should be fine, since equal values always come from exact same vert(right?..) , but UVs... I have no idea what all possible cases may be here. The data must be converted on export - no idea how that happens and how overlapping UVs are merged or stored in Blender - I mean they seam to be separate equal values for face corners in Blender. No idea how equal they are. Unless you tested it thoroughly.
